# How to make button available directly from function

Tags: android, button, mvvm

Hi i am making an app that follows the MVVM structure i took a look at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7UxPYxgBoA&t=152s in this tutorial the person that teaches use code that looks like this...

```
private fun initializeUi() {
    val factory = InjectorUtils.provideQuotesViewModelFactory()
    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(QuotesViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getQuotes().observe(this, Observer { quotes ->
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        quotes.forEach{ quote ->
            stringBuilder.append("$quote\n\n")
        }
        textView_quotes.text = stringBuilder.toString()
    })

    button_add_quote.setOnClickListener {
        val quote = Quote(editText_quote.text.toString(), editText_author.text.toString())
        viewModel.addQuote(quote)
        editText_quote.setText("")
        editText_author.setText("")
    }
}
```

as you can see he doesnt initialize a variable to find the button. how is this possible... i tried to do this in a fragment and it does not work? tell me if you need further code and ill add it in.

Reading up on Kotlin synthetics in the official documentation helps alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using Kotlin synthetics, which is a way to bind the layout xml to the activity or fragment class. You can see it in the source code for the project on GitHub:

https://github.com/ResoCoder/mvvm-android-architecture-crash-course/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/resocoder/mvvmbasicstut/ui/quotes/QuotesActivity.kt#L10

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_quotes.*
```

However, Kotlin synthetics has been deprecated and you should be using view binding instead.  More info here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration